# Complex wifi bug's been confusing me for days

Tags: drivers, wireless, laptop, hp, proprietary

I've been trying to get Ubuntu 16.10 to run on this HP Split 13 X2, and it seems even what works for other HP users isn't working for me. I've been at this for days now trying everything I could find. I guess I'm still a novice compared to a lot of you, but I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling drivers, all kinds of recommended terminal fixes, and even completely reinstalling the OS from a fresh download. When I managed to un-hardblock or install software for proprietary drivers I only find something else keeps 'disabling network', it's been a real goose chase..

sudo lshw -C network gets me:

```
[ [sudo] password for queuevius: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:2f:90:ae
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-22-generic firmware=17.352738.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:60 memory:b2400000-b2401fff ]
```

And "$ sudo lspci -vnn | awk -vRs= '/[02.0]/'" gets me:

```
[07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)]
```

I switch wifi on, in 'settings', and it just switches back off instantly. I'm guessing that's because the actual card's not enabled but I've been trying to enable it in so many ways now my brain's turning to mush.

In software and updates > additional drivers it says the device is 'unknown: unknown', and I can choose from 'do not use the device' or 'Using processor microcode firmware for Intell CPUs from intell-microcode (proprietary) But I select the driver, even after trying to enable it, downloading ndiswrapper and all this other stuff, it says its connected but the wifi's still 'disabled'.

sudo iwlist scan is telling me 'wlp7s0's interface doesn't support scanning' and 'network is down'. "lo" isn't supporting scanning either.

iwconfig tells me wlp7s0 has an ESSID that's off, a managed access point that's 'not-associated' and for "tx-power=" is says 'off'. Meanwhile it says 'lo' has 'no wireless extentions'

For some reason over half the commands in the Ubuntu Terminal Command cheat sheet just come back with '______ not found'. Did they really change that much in 16.10? I've been using Ubuntu for years and I gotta say, as much as I totally am still a rookie, I've never seen so many commands simply not be recognized. What is goin on?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of the actual wireless/network device as obtained for example from `sudo lshw -C network` and/or `sudo lspci -vnn | awk -vRS= '/\[02.0\]/'`

Answer (score 0):

In terminal enter

```
echo "blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: The terminal didn't say anything back but also didn't start doing anything either. I've tried it twice, waited for it to do something, rebooted twice. Doesn't seem to do anything